# Is there an Excel equivalent way to mimic pandas.DataFrame.iloc?

Tags: python, excel

Given an Excel spreadsheet with 30 rows of data that looks like:

```
|------|------------|
|  id  |    text    |
|------|------------|
|   1  |    apple   |
|   2  |    apple   |
|   3  |   banana   |
|   4  |    apple   |
|   5  |   orange   |
|  ... |    ...     |
|  30  |   orange   |
|------|------------|
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do an integer-location based indexing. For example, if I wanted to return the first 3 rows starting from the 2nd row, I would use `df.iloc[2:5]`:

```
expected output:
|------|------------|
|   2  |    apple   |
|   3  |   banana   |
|   4  |    apple   |
|------|------------|
```

I would ultimately want to specify (1) the starting position and (2) the number of rows to return from the starting position, in Excel (e.g. return 10 rows starting from id=21). I've tried creating an array using INDEX but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: check INDIRECT Function. It's what you are looking for

Comment: Are you asking for an excel function? Try [OFFSET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two functions for these:

MATCH will find a value in a range and return their position
INDIRECT will allow you to specify a string representing a range, and it will return the values contained in that range.

> [MATCH
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
>
> [INDIRECT
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Made a test like this:

[image]

My formula in K9 is:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(L4;A:A;0)&":B"&(MATCH(L4;A:A;0)-1+L5))
```

This is how it works:

1. `MATCH(L4;A:A;0)` will find the ID position in column A. Because I said i am searching in whole column, value returned is the row number where the ID is. So if I want to find ID 2, it will return `3`.
2. We combine the number from previous step with a string, to get a string like `A3:B5`. The 5 is obtained from `MATCH(L4;A:A;0)-1+L5)` where i get the row number of the ID I want to find, sum up the number of rows to get, and substract 1.
3. `INDIRECT("A3:B5")` is what i want and it's returned.

**NOTE:** Depending on your Excel version, INDIRECT will auto expand to adyacent cells or not. Maybe you have to drag it manually

A video showing how it changes if i want to search different id or different number of rows:

[image]

**NOTE 2:** If the id is not found, MATCH will raise an error, and the formula will not work.

Check first if the ID exists in column A with COUNTIF and if true, then you do MATCH and INDIRECT. Something like this:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A:A;L4)>0;INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(L4;A:A;0)&":B"&(MATCH(L4;A:A;0)-1+L5));"ID NOT FOUND")`

Same if number of rows returned is 0 or less.

Comment: `INDIRECT` is a volitile function, and should not be (over) used, especially when there is a non- volitile alternative,  as there is in this case - `INDEX`

Answer (score 1):

There are various formulas depending on your version of Excel.

If you have dynamic arrays (Excel 2016+ if I recall correctly), you can enter the following in a single cell.
If your Excel does not have dynamic arrays, a modification would be necessary.

```
=INDEX(fruitTbl,Start,0):INDEX(fruitTbl,Count+Start-1,0)
```

I converted the data range to an Excel Table, but you can use regular addressing if you prefer.  With a Table, the first row of data would be `1` since Table returns only the data body range.

[image]

*to try if you do not have dynamic arrays*

*Enter in some cell:*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(fruitTbl,Start,0):INDEX(fruitTbl,Count+Start-1,0),ROWS($1:1),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

- *Then drag one column to the right*
- *Select both cells and drag down at least until you start seeing blank cells*